# Foreign Key Multi Table Possibility

Tags: mysql, innodb, polymorphic-associations

I have seen similar posts and have not found a definitive answer.

I have a series of tables that store data about certain events. Each of these tables have the same structure. Each of these tables has a foreign key constraint for an `id` showing what item the data is related to.

Each of these tables `id` structure is also the same `CHAR(24)`. The tables these `ids` come from must remain separate because they are all completely different.

I am interested in combining all of my data tables into one with a foreign key being constrained to one of 3 tables. So, a row in my data table will have to have an `id` that is present in one of the three tables. Additionally this foreign key will need the possibility of `ON DELETE` settings. Is this possible? And to that, is this poor design?

```
Items A
 - id
 - ...

Items B
 - id
 - ...

Items C
 - id
 - ...

Data
 - id FK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you're describing is sometimes called [polymorphic-associations](/questions/tagged/polymorphic-associations) but it should be a clue that it's not good design because **you can't make a foreign key constraint for it.** That is, the `FOREIGN KEY` syntax only allows you to reference one table, not three.

The only way you could make a real foreign key constraint that performs `ON DELETE` actions is to make three separate foreign keys:

```
Data
 - idA FK
 - idB FK
 - idC FK
```

For a given row in Data, presumably only one of these three foreign keys would be non-NULL. The other two would be NULL. Ensuring this could be done in a trigger or CHECK constraint, or else you would just have to implement it in application logic (i.e. don't insert a row with more than one of these columns non-NULL).

Polymorphic associations, that is storing a single column that may reference one of three different tables, is not a valid relational design.

You can see past answers I've written about polymorphic associations: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpolymorphic-associations%5D+user%3A20860